# Postman not shown the output of the get request

Tags: node.js, postman

I am engaging with a node.js project. i use the Visual studio code as the text editor. I use postman for testing the API requests.

my **app.js** file as follow

```
import express from 'express';
var app = express();
var PORT = 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.json({
      msg: 'ruwan liyanage'
   });
});

const invoices = [];

app.get('/invoices', (req, res) => {
   res.json(invoices);
});

app.listen(PORT, function() {
   console.log('Hi welcome');
});

//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map
```

The postman working for the first function of the **app.js** which is in follow.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        msg: 'ruwan liyanage'
    });
});
```

As a result postman shows this.

```
{
   "msg": "ruwan liyanage"
}
```

[image]

Then why not working for the second function which is is  follow

```
const invoices = [];

app.get('/invoices', (req, res) => {
    res.json(invoices);
});
```

[image]

when I enter the `http://localhost:3000/invoices` it showed this sort of output
`Cannot GET /invoices`

What should i do

Comment: `invoices` is an array, not a json object. however, youre getting a 404 error so the `invoices` api/route isnt on the server

Comment: when i run this on brwser the output was `Cannot GET /invoices` the expected result is an empty array. then what should i do

Comment: make sure that you have saved the app.js file, and check the api/route is correct

Comment: what do you mean by the api/route. are you asking about the `http://localhost:3000/invoices`.

Comment: @ruwanliyanage I tried your code and it works perfectly fine for me. what version of node are you using ?

Comment: i mean make sure that the `app.get('/invoices'...` bit is saved and make sure you are calling the same thing in your browser

Comment: Node version 10.15.3

Comment: Yes i called the same thing in browser.

Comment: still not success for me. Then what should be the problem.Is there has any special configuration for the postman or browser

Comment: Have you restarted the app since adding the /invoices route?  I'd also edit the invoices function to be something simple like the root api by returning...     res.json({
        msg: 'invoices'
    });